# ALL_PART_COL_STATISTICS in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am a newbie to database. Can anyone please explain on how to use ALL_PART_COL_STATISTICS of Data dictionary in oracle?

I searched on the web and I am pretty blank. I am trying to show an example of using the ALL_PART_COL_STATISTICS and explain what does it do.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2001.htm#REFRN20154

This is a table I have created:

```
    CREATE TABLE TBL_SALES_PERSONNEL
(
 SALES_PERSONNEL_ID INT CONSTRAINT PK_SALES_PERSONNEL PRIMARY   
  KEY,
  SALES_PERSONNEL_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  GENDER VARCHAR2(1),
  CONTACT_NUMBER INT
);

INSERT INTO TBL_SALES_PERSONNEL VALUES
(1,'BORIS','M',11111111);
INSERT INTO TBL_SALES_PERSONNEL VALUES
(2,'GEORGIE','M',11111112);
INSERT INTO TBL_SALES_PERSONNEL VALUES
(3,'ALLE','F',11111113);
INSERT INTO TBL_SALES_PERSONNEL VALUES
(4,'JOSEPH','M',11111114);
INSERT INTO TBL_SALES_PERSONNEL VALUES
(5,'JULE','F',11111115);
```

Please note that the table I have created, I have no idea if ALL_PART_COL_STATISTICS can be used on it cause I have literally no idea on data dictionary and I just randomly created a table.

Comment: Can you add more Informations on what you try to accomplish. By the way you created a non partioned table so why do you want to get statistics of it?

Comment: What i'm trying to accomplish is , how do i explain what does  ALL_PART_COL_STATISTICS do and i have to show an example on using that.

Comment: Should i change the whole question into just an question without any of the code above?

Comment: If you want to use this view than you have to create a partioned table in the First Place.

Comment: Can you post an example? I am very clueless right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people said, that view only shows partitioned tables, so if you want your table to show up, it has to be partitioned.

```
CREATE TABLE my_test
(col1    NUMBER NOT NULL,
 col2    DATE   NOT NULL)
PARTITION BY HASH (col1)
PARTITIONS 4;

select * from ALL_PART_COL_STATISTICS where table_name = 'MY_TEST';
```

Comment: it say partition is not enabled

Comment: Yes, partitioning is an Enterprise Edition feature. You won't be able to use it, so your ALL_PART_COL_STATISTICS view will always be empty. Possibly you want to use ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS instead.

Comment: do u know how to use DBA_STREAMS_ADD_COLUMN too? is it the same way as the parititoned?

Comment: No, it's very different. From the documentation, it looks like if you're using the Oracle Streams product, you can use that view to see which Rules add columns to LCRs. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28321/strms_over.htm#i1006084